# Single key with multiple values in property

Tags: java

I having a property file containing below data :

```
acqurierSystemAlias=CTC0,CTC1,CTC2,CTC3,CTC4,FEXCO,AMEX,DINERS
```

now in the main program :

```
String acqurierSA = "CTC1";
String[] acqurierSystemAlias = properties.getProperty("acqurierSystemAlias").split(",");

for(String xyz: acqurierSystemAlias){
    if(xyz.equalsIgnoreCase(acqurierSA)) {
        System.out.println("true");
    } else {
        System.out.println("false");
    }
}
```

This is returning me : `false`, `true`, `false`, `false`, `false`

My requirement is just to return `true` if the `acqurierSA` is in the propertyfile or else return `false`, I want only a single value. Currently it is returning me the values in loop.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could make a `list` form `Array` and then check with `contains()`

```
String[] acqurierSystemAlias = properties.getProperty("acqurierSystemAlias").split(",");

List<String> lList=Arrays.asList(acqurierSystemAlias);

boolean found=lList.contains(acqurierSA );
System.out.println(found);
```

No need to traverse through the array.

Answer (score 3):

You could use a dedicated variable to do this:

```
boolean found = false;

for(String xyz: acqurierSystemAlias){
    if(xyz.equalsIgnoreCase(acqurierSA)){
        found = true;
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(found);
```

Answer (score 1):

maybe you need not split the property
just

```
System.out.println(("," + properties.getProperty("acqurierSystemAlias") + ",").contains("," +acqurierSA+ "," ));
```

Comment: What about, property string: `a,b,,c` and searching for `b,` - false positive (shouldn't be in the list since it only contains `a`, `b`, (empty), `c`)

Comment: So, there is a question, if your values may contains ',', you cannot split by ',' because maybe 'a,b,,c' is means 'a', 'b,', 'c'. If your values do not contain ',', you cannot using 'b,' to search.

Comment: You can split using `','` but you shouldn't get to search with a string containing it... and (in my mind) you should never get positive results if you do.

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
String acqurierSA = "CTC1";
String[] acqurierSystemAlias = properties.getProperty("acqurierSystemAlias").split(",");

List<String> strList = Arrays.asList(acqurierSystemAlias);
strList.contains(acqurierSA);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public String processMountCheck() {
        logger.info("Logging an INFO-about Directory exists or not.");
        processPropFile();
        String[] urls = prop.getProperty("URL").split(",");
        List<String> list = Arrays.asList(urls);
        String[] folder = prop.getProperty("DIRECTORY").split(",");
        List<String> folders = Arrays.asList(folder);
        for (int i = 0; i < folders.size(); i++) {
            String k = folders.get(i);
            File file = new File(k);
            if (file.isDirectory()) {
                logger.info("Connected to a Directory!"+folders.get(i));
                if (file.list().length > 0) {
                    logger.info("Directory is not empty!");
                } else {
                    logger.info("Directory is empty!");
                }
            } else {
                logger.error("Invalid Directory!");
                // System.out.println("This is not a directory");
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Check this answer for mount check,loading values for single key with multiple values in properties file